# How can I calculate the percent of a raster cell covered by a polygon?

Tags: raster, polygon, arcgis-10.3, raster-calculator

First, I am going to try and intersect a raster and a polygon shapefile. I'm not 100% sure how to do this (or if I need to do this for the next step), so if you have any suggestions please let me know! Then, my next task is as follows:

If the overlayed/intersected polygon covers > 50% of a raster grid cell, then the grid cell gets a value of "1". If not, the grid cell gets a value of "0".

Does anyone know how I can execute this task in ArcMap 10.3.1?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a problem best done as in vector. Imagine the scenario below:

[image: Example]

Cells are coloured by their value. First thing it is not clear if you want to ask the question of > 50% for individual cells or group of cells. So for example the polygon cover is > 50% for the red central cell but that is clearly part of a group of cells representing the same feature, so in that case its less than 50% of coverage. You need to make that distinction.

Assuming its the later and its group of cells you are processing then:

- [convert the raster to polygons](http://help.arcgis.com/En/Arcgisdesktop/10.0/Help/index.html#//001200000008000000)
- run an [Union](http://help.arcgis.com/En/Arcgisdesktop/10.0/Help/index.html#/Union/00080000000s000000/)
- From the resulting combination of attributes you'll be able to [summarize](http://help.arcgis.com/En/Arcgisdesktop/10.0/Help/index.html#/Summary_Statistics/00080000001z000000/) the results to work out proportion of coverage and code into 1 or 0.
- Then join that back to your vectorized grid and optionally convert back to raster.

So this is a multi-staged processing of data requiring you to keep track of unique ID values so data can be summarized and joined back.

Comment: thank you for the help! How should I go about doing this if it's actually individual cells that I am processing?

Comment: Your question implies you have no interest in the actual value the cell contains. If this is the case you can convert the raster to a point dataset, create a unique ID field then convert the point dataset back into a raster using the ID field as the value field. This will create a raster where every cell has a unique value. Obviously need to set cell size to original grid and extent.